# Lib em python para converter PDF/EPUB para txt

Tags: python, nltk

vou usar o NLTK mas estou precisando extrairo texto puro. O material que eu tenho está em epub e pdf, então preciso de uma lib que converta um desses formatos para txt. Alguém sabe se tem algo do tipo? Obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ja utilizei varias libs para isso, a que me proporcionou os melhores resultados, foi a tika, para instalar:

```
pip install tika
```

Utilização:

```
from tika import parser

file = 'path/to/file'

# Fazendo parse
data = parser.from_file(file)

# Imprimindo o conteudo do parse
text = data['content']
print(text)
```